How can I filter from several params in data-id
I'm trying to make filter from several divs:
<div class="sgmt" data-id="orange, apple">First one</div>  
<div class="sgmt" data-id="onion, apple">Second one</div>  
<div class="sgmt" data-id="onion, grape">Third one</div>

<script>  
$param="orange";

$('.sgmt').filter(function() {   
if ($param == '0') {      
return '*';  
} else {      
return $(this).data('view') == $param;  
}  }).addClass("sgmt-show");  
</script>

But, it's not working with several params inside data-id, what I'm doing wrong?

You can use includes method

You have to pass the part after data- as a argument to the .data() method but you are passing view.
Solution
For data-id you should pass $(this).data('id').
Note: the part after data- must be in lowercase
Then for comparing multiple params in data-id, you can use .includes method


let $param = '4';
$('.sgmt')
.filter(function () {
  if ($param == '0') {
    return '*';
  } else {
    const params = $(this).data('id').split(', ');
    console.log(params)
    return params.includes($param);
  }
})
.addClass('sgmt-show');
.sgmt{
  color: green
}
.sgmt-show{
  color:red
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sgmt" data-id="apple, 4">First one</div>  
<div class="sgmt" data-id="44, orangeGreen, apple">Second one</div>  
<div class="sgmt" data-id="onion, grape">Third one</div>




But if i will have params like "orangeBlue", "orangeGreen" it will be shown also, but i don't need this.

I've change to the case we are taking, but it didn't shows orangeGreen when param like orangeBlue. see above

i will use numeric id's, when i will try to filter by parameter "8" it will show also "88", it's possible to make includes hard equal?

I've changed, now it looks for exact match

@SergeiShumailov this is a wrong solution



.sgmt-show{
  color:red;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sgmt" data-id="orange, apple">First one</div>  
<div class="sgmt" data-id="onion, apple">Second one</div>  
<div class="sgmt" data-id="onion, grape">Third one</div>

<script>  
$param="orange";

$('.sgmt')
  .filter((_, el) => $param === '0' || el.dataset.id.split(', ').includes($param))
  .addClass("sgmt-show");  
</script>




@YuvarajM nope, your string split is wrong

@YuvarajM "apple, 4".split(',') is wrong

That's what in you answer Mr @Alex see above

@YuvarajM i use ', ' instead of ',', see the space

Okay, however if you know what the difference let me know

awaiting for you answer

@YuvarajM replace "4, apple" with "apple, 4" in your answer and see the difference
